# How do I run pyspark with jupyter notebook?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to fire the jupyter notebook when I run the command `pyspark` in the console. When I type it now, it only starts and interactive shell in the console. However, this is not convenient to type long lines of code. Is there are way to connect the jupyter notebook to pyspark shell? Thanks.

Comment: how is the setup working?

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you already have spark and jupyter notebooks installed and they work flawlessly  independent of each other.

If that is the case, then follow the steps below and you should be able to fire up a jupyter notebook with a (py)spark backend.

1. Go to your spark installation folder and there should be a `bin` directory there:
   `/path/to/spark/bin`
2. Create a file, let's call it `start_pyspark.sh`
3. Open `start_pyspark.sh` and write something like:

   ```
       #!/bin/bash

   export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/path/to/anaconda3/bin/python
   export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/path/to/anaconda3/bin/jupyter
   export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --NotebookApp.open_browser=False --NotebookApp.ip='*' --NotebookApp.port=8880"

   pyspark "$@"
   ```

Replace the `/path/to ...` with the path where you have installed your python and jupyter binaries respectively.

4. Most probably this step is already done, but just in case
   Modify your `~/.bashrc` file by adding the following lines

   ```
       # Spark
       export PATH="/path/to/spark/bin:/path/to/spark/sbin:$PATH"
       export SPARK_HOME="/path/to/spark"
       export SPARK_CONF_DIR="/path/to/spark/conf"
   ```

Run `source ~/.bashrc` and you are set.

Go ahead and try `start_pyspark.sh`.
You could also give arguments to the script, something like
`start_pyspark.sh --packages dibbhatt:kafka-spark-consumer:1.0.14`.

Hope it works out for you.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have Spark installed wherever you are going to run Jupyter, I'd recommend you use [findspark](https://github.com/minrk/findspark). Once you `pip install findspark`, you can just

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="myAppName")
```

... and go

Answer (score 3):

```
cd project-folder/
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv
```

This should create a folder "venv/" inside your project folder.

Run the virtualenv by typing

```
source venv/bin/activate
pip install jupyter
```

This should start your virtualenv. Then go to ~/.bash_profile and type

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

Then type `source ~/.bash_profile` in the console.
You should be good to go after this.
If you type `pyspark` in the console, a jupyter notebook will fire-up

You can also check that object `sqlConnector` is available in your notebook by typing `sqlConnector` and executing the ipython notebook cell.

You can also check out [Unable to load pyspark inside virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959550/unable-to-load-pyspark-inside-virtualenv)

Answer (score 1):

Save your self a lot of configuration headaches, just run a Docker container: https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/all-spark-notebook/

Answer (score 0):

Download spark from the website i have downloaded spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7,jupyter-notebook

```
mak@mak-Aspire-A515-51G:~$ chmod -R 777 spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7
mak@mak-Aspire-A515-51G:~$ export SPARK_HOME='/home/mak/spark-2.2.0-bin- 
hadoop2.7'
mak@mak-Aspire-A515-51G:~$ export PATH=$SPARK_HOME:$PATH
mak@mak-Aspire-A515-51G:~$ export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH
mak@mak-Aspire-A515-51G:~$ export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
mak@mak-Aspire-A515-51G:~$ export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
mak@mak-Aspire-A515-51G:~$ export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
```

Go to spark directory and open python3 and import spark it will be succesful.

```
 mak@mak-Aspire-A515-51G:~/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python$ python3
 Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 18:10:19) 
 [GCC 7.2.0] on linux
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import pyspark

mak@mak-Aspire-A515-51G:~/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python$ jupyter-notebook
import pyspark
```

if you want to open jupyter from the outside of Spark directory then you need to follow the below steps

```
mak@mak-Aspire-A515-51G:~$ pip3 install findspark

mak@mak-Aspire-A515-51G:~$ python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 18:10:19) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyspark
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'
>>> import findspark
>>> findspark.init('/home/mak/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7')
>>> import pyspark


mak@mak-Aspire-A515-51G:~$ jupyter-notebook 
import findspark
findspark.init('/home/mak/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7')
import pyspark
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Steps to Run Spark with Jupyter Notebook

1.) Install Spark Binaries independently from Apache Foundation website and add Spark binaries to PATH

2.) ADD the following entries in your .bash_profile or .bashrc

`export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON='jupyter'`

`export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook --no-browser --port=<port-number>`

3.) Install findspark package in your conda environment

`conda install -c conda-forge findspark`

4.) Open jupyter notebook

5.) Run below commands in a cell

```
findspark.init()
findspark.find()
import pyspark
findspark.find()
```

6.) Create Spark Session :

`from pyspark.sql import SparkSession`

`spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()`

7.) Read Files and Do whatever operations you want

`df=spark.read.csv("file-path")`