# Unable to load pyspark inside virtualenv

Tags: pyspark, virtualenv, jupyter-lab, apache-spark-2.1.1

I had installed pyspark in a python virtualenv. I have also installed jupyterlab which was newly released http://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html in the virtualenv. I was unable to fire pyspark within a jupyter-notebook in such a way that I have the SparkContext variable available.

Answer (score 5):

First fire the virtualenv

```
source venv/bin/activate
export SPARK_HOME={path_to_venv}/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter-lab
```

Before this I hope you have done:`pip install pyspark` and `pip install jupyterlab` inside your virtualenv

To check, once your jupyterlab is open, type `sc` in a box in the jupyterlab and you should have the SparkContext object available and the output should be this:

```
SparkContext
Spark UI
Version
v2.2.1
Master
local[*]
AppName
PySparkShell
```

Comment: For me, Spark 3.2.0 + Python 3.9, this works: `SPARK_HOME=.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook' pyspark`

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your $PYSPARK_PYTHON with your virtualenv

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON={path/to/your/virtualenv}/bin/python
```

That solved my case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, working with windows, python 3.7.4 and spark 3.1.1., the problem was that pyspark was looking for python3.exe that did not exist. I made a copy of venv/Scripts/python.exe and renamed venv/Scripts/python3.exe