# How to start graphframes on spark on pyspark on juypter on docker?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, graphframes

Been playing with pyspark on juypter all day with no issues. Just by simply using the docker image `juypter/pyspark-notebook`, 90% of everything I need is packaged (YAY!)

I would like to start exploring using GraphFrames, which sits on top of GraphX which sits on top of Spark. Has anyone gotten this combination to work?

Essentially, according to the documentation, I just need to pass "--packages graphframes:xxyyzz" when running pyspark to download and run graphframes. Problem is that juypter is already running as soon as the container comes up.

I've tried passing the "--packages" line as an environment variable (-e) for both JUYPTER_SPARK_OPTS and SPARK_OPTS when running docker run and that didn't work. I found that I *can* do `pip install graphframes` from a terminal, which gets me part of the way -- the python libraries are installed, but the java ones are not "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.graphframes.GraphFramePythonAPI".

The [image specifics documentation](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/specifics.html#apache-spark) does not appear to offer any insights on how to deploy a Spark Package to the image.

Is there a certain place to throw the graphframes .jar? Is there a command to install a spark package post-docker? Is there a magic argument to `docker run` that would install this?

I bet there's a really simple answer to this --Or am I in high cotton here?

References:

- [No module named graphframes Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286139/no-module-named-graphframes-jupyter-notebook)
- [How do I run pyspark with jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915274/how-do-i-run-pyspark-with-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 4):

So the answer was quite simple:

From the [gist here](https://gist.github.com/parente/c95fdaba5a9a066efaab), we need to simply tell juypter to add the `--packages` line to the `SPARK_SUBMIT` with something like this to the top of my notebook. Spark goes out and installs the package when grabbing the context:

```py
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12 pyspark-shell'
```

Keep a watch on the versions available at the [graphframes package](https://spark-packages.org/package/graphframes/graphframes), which for now, means graphframes 0.8.1 on spark 3.0 on scala 2.12.

Comment: Confirmed this answer worked as of this comment date. Just add the above in a cell in the notebook and you can see in your terminal where the docker image is started that it downloads and installs. Thank you!